# JOIN without Duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

`fct_collection`

[image]

`fct_collection_dr_details`

[image]

my target is to combine them without duplicate like this.

[image]

edited

[image]

but my output is this

[image]

here is my query

```
SELECT a.appkey,
       a.drnumber,
       a.amt,
       b.prnumber,
       b.prdate
FROM fct_collection_dr_details AS a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(appkey) AS 'appkey',
            MAX(prnumber) AS 'prnumber',
            prdate
     FROM fct_collection
     GROUP BY prdate) AS b ON a.appkey = b.appkey
```

I used to join them by `appkey`

here are the tables

fct_collection

```
         appkey             prnumber    prdate
10/04/2017 15:49:2032s1gXox 1234567   2017-10-04
10/05/2017 14:29:142qmvYRJM 2356489   2017-10-05

fct_collection_dr_details

    appkey                 drnumber   amt
10/04/2017 15:49:2032s1gXox 12345     2500
10/05/2017 14:29:142qmvYRJM 234569    5000
10/05/2017 14:29:142qmvYRJM 698745    10000
```

Comment: Is SELECT DISTINCT already sufficient?

Comment: well grouping 2 table will produce distinct data but when joining them is my prob.

Comment: I see no duplicated rows, can u explain more?

Comment: @Amani Really? Look at appkey, prdate.

Comment: hi guys dont know why but when the joining occurs the table duplicates which is not what i need. is there any possibilty that remain the 1st instance
 of duplicate the data then join it in the 1st instance also from other table

Comment: @Amani and also the `prnumber`

Comment: @NardongBagsik Edit your question please, do not post sample data, code, desired results as images, most of SO users need to see formatted text, that way they can test and you get beter answers.

Comment: @Sami noted sir. Kindly wait:)

Comment: @Sami i see that `appkey` is duplicated .. but considering the whole row there is no duplicated rows.

Comment: Im very sorry guys please see the updated post. I change the `fct_collection` table sorry

Comment: @NardongBagsik I was about to ask you about your tables, because I was confused since both tables looked almost the same.

Comment: @Amani sir and to everyone Im very sorry the 1st table is the same as the ouput. soooooo sorry :(

Comment: done editing with the data below

Comment: The output is you get is correct and as expected for SQL. What you are seeking is a "report" and that isn't what SQL does. Usually the style of presentation you are seeking is performed elsewhere in a report writer or "presentation layer". In short your expectation on output control in SQL will not be met.

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks for the info but still looking for other solutions

Comment: Well there a amultitude of posibilities. What technology is to be used?  PHP? Html? C#?. .net? Clickview? Jaspersoft?  But do not confuse report presentation with SQL you will be disappointed.

Comment: I am using PHP and HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try left join

```
SELECT a.appkey, a.drnumber, a.amt, b.prnumber, b.prdate 
FROM fct_collection_dr_details AS a 
left JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(appkey) AS 'appkey', MAX(prnumber) AS 'prnumber', prdate 
FROM fct_collection GROUP BY prdate) AS b ON a.appkey = b.appkey
```

Comment: still same output